# How do I use FirestoreProperty with DocumentReference?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore in a Unity application. I have a field on a document as type reference. When trying to create a custom object class for this data (as shown here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects), I am unable to create the documentReference with ConvertTo.
[image]

The data class

```
[FirestoreData]
public class LeaderboardItem
{
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public int Score { get; set; }
    
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public DocumentReference ScoreRef { get; set; }
}
```

Attempt to transform into its own object

```
documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<LeaderboardItem>();
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you right now, but a stopgap answer is that generally Firestore can't store documents in other documents (it always interlaces collection->document->collection->document). You're probably best off _for now_ storing a string there and manually expanding that into a new document reference. Feel free to also ask on https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues

Comment: If you (or anyone else) is still having this issue, we'd love you to open a bug  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues

Comment: Are you getting an error when attempting to transform it? I have also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202384/16025692) to a question similar to yours that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the FirestoreDocumentId attribute on the string or DocumentReferance property, for the string you will get the document ID, and for the DocumentReferance you will get the document referance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).